# MOUSE_DOWN and MOUSE_UP not dispatching for custom Sprite

Tags: actionscript-3, events

I have created a custom Sprite object which is not dispatching the MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN or MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP events.  It is properly dispatching MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE events.

All event listeners are verified to be registered.

I apologize if this is a common or excessively simple question, but I have spent the last hour Googling and reading StackOverflow for questions or answers that fit my situation and simply have not found one.  As far as I know, Sprite is an InteractiveObject and therefore should be dispatching all three of these events rather than only the MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE events.

**Class Declaration:**

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.geom.*;

public class CustomSprite extends Sprite {
```

**Object Initialization in main.as**

```
    var circle:CustomSprite = new CustomSprite();
    circle.graphics.lineStyle(3,0x00FF00);
    circle.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF,.5);
    circle.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,50);
    circle.graphics.endFill();
    circle.x = 100;
    circle.y = 100;
```

**Event Listener Registration in Constructor:**

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,mouseDownListener);
if (hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN)) trace("MOUSE_DOWN listener exists");

addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,mouseUpListener);
if (hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP)) trace("MOUSE_UP listener exists");

addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,mouseMoveListener);
if (hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE)) trace("MOUSE_MOVE listener exists");
```

**Event Listener Registration Output:**

```
MOUSE_DOWN listener exists
MOUSE_UP listener exists
MOUSE_MOVE listener exists
```

**Listener Functions as Part of CustomSprite Class:**

```
    private function mouseDownListener(e:MouseEvent):void {
        trace("mouseDownListener");
    }

    private function mouseUpListener(e:MouseEvent):void {
        trace("mouseUpListener");
    }

    private function mouseMoveListener(e:MouseEvent):void {
        trace("mouseMoveListener");
    }
```

**Output after hovering over object and clicking several times:**

```
mouseMoveListener
mouseMoveListener
mouseMoveListener
mouseMoveListener
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer - it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you add more context?

Comment: I added the way the object is initialized in main.as.  What other context would be helpful?

Comment: Can you provide more details on the sprite class itself? Your implementation? Your CustomSprite may be causing problems with the "mouseDown" and "mouseUp" listeners.

Comment: Is that exactly how you're adding your event listeners? Exactly? No <object>.addEventListener?

Comment: Take a look at what I posted, if you're already doing this I'll take it down.

Comment: @CharlesSmartt I created a new class with only the code seen here, so the class has no other code to be causing problems.  The addEventListeners are in the constructor of the CustomSprite class.

Comment: And here's the documentation for Sprite showing that it is eligible for mouseDown and mouseUp events which are represented as MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN and MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#eventSummary

Comment: I'll respond to your answer below as well to make sure you see this.  It's working now.  As if by magic.  Okay then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is looks like from the source you have provided is that you aren't adding the event listeners to the circle itself. This snippet I tested worked, provided I don't have your `CustomSprite`, but just the `Sprite`.

```
var circle:CustomSprite = new CustomSprite();
circle.graphics.lineStyle(3,0x00FF00);
circle.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF,.5);
circle.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,50);
circle.graphics.endFill();
circle.x = 100;
circle.y = 100;

circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function(event:MouseEvent):void{
   trace("mouseDown");
});
circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function(event:MouseEvent):void{
   trace("mouseUp");
});
circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, function(event:MouseEvent):void{
   trace("mouseMove");
});
```

Comment: I apologize for the confusion.  My addEventListeners are inside the constructor of the CustomSprite class, so as I understand it they are implicitly passed to the object.

Comment: To confirm that it wasn't the issue, I just tried adding an event listener with an anonymous function in Main directly to the circle object after it had been added to the display hierarchy and it still did not fire.  When I added one directly to the stage that one fired, so I am using the correct MouseEvent as well.

Comment: I just accepted the answer, as someone coming in from Google might be helped by it.  Anyway, it started working as I had it.  By magic.